# sprintf/printf/fprintf - tool to identify format specifiers mismatches to param counts in multiple src files

Tags: c, gdb

I am working on several old programs written in c (100s of files) that have had some mismatch with `printf()` family functions. Specifically the number of parameters and number of format specifiers mismatch.
Is there a tool that exists that I could use to easily find the line numbers in the src files. These programs are segfaulting at run time, but I want to proactively find the issues as opposed to using gdb to find the bug.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're building with GCC then add more warnings when building and the compiler will tell you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `clang` and `gcc` will throw warnings by default. You might try using `-Wall` and `-Wextra` if for some reason you don't see the compiler warnings.

## Clang Example:

```
$ cc parg.c -o parg
parg.c:5:34: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
        printf("arg1: %i\narg2: %i\n", 8);
                                ~^
parg.c:6:33: warning: data argument not used by format string
      [-Wformat-extra-args]
        printf("arg3: %i\n", 3, 5);
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~     ^
```

If your issue is that you're dynamically building your format strings, then you need to review how you're doing that. I don't know of any software that reviews code and finds out if you're likely to pass bad format strings, since it's such a open-ended problem.

## Edit

`-Wall` and `-Wextra` are useful flags, but I noticed that it's a bit of [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) for me to suggest blaring out all warnings when really what you want are `-Wformat` and `-Wformat-extra-args` (`-Wformat` actually turns on `-Wformat-extra-args`). And, as @JonathanLeffler pointed out in the comments, `-Wformat-nonliteral` could be useful for ensuring that you look at instances where you pass non-literal strings and analyze them to see if you're likely to cause runtime errors.

Comment: The only time this doesn't work is, unsurprisingly, when the format string is not a literal string (e.g. because you're dealing with the L10N aspect of I18N — localization and internationalization for those lucky enough not to have encountered the terms).  There are ways around that; there is a separate `-Wformat-nonliteral` option that comes into play, and such warnings have to be treated with the utmost care and attention to detail.  The basic answer is right though; the GCC and Clang compilers provide good protection.